# Browser specific / conditional JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, opera

Is it possible to write browser specific (Conditional) JS code clike CSS? If it is possible I was looking for some references.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is pretty vague then my answer can't really be anything but. Using user-agent detection is completely unnecessary in the vast majority of cases, and will quite often give you incorrect results. You'd be much better off thinking in terms of *features* than *browsers*, and checking for feature support at runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623555/load-different-jquery-script-if-browser-is-internet-explorer  is what i was looking for actually.